# Simulated Click event between overlay elements

Tags: javascript, time, click, element

There is a function HTML / CSS / JS that allows a div (with z-index: 2000) to simulate the click event, when it overlay for 5s on an image hotspot (with a z-index: 1000).

Comment: Why can't you simply call the function or the method relative to the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a click event on the element that overlays and within the handler, trigger a click on the image element:

```
<div id="Overlay" style="z-index:2000">
</div>
<img id="OverlayedOn" src="/myimage" style="z-index:1000"/>

<script>
$('#Overlay').click(
    function(){
        $('#OverlayedOn').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that the click event must be made by the superposition of two elements, without the use of touch, mouse or other external devices. this overlapping is possible because the element present in the lower level is in motion, while the element is fixed in the upper level.

Comment: @AndreaRossi, yes you can programmatically fire the click event by doing $('#OverlayedOn').click(); anytime. Do you know when the elements are superpositioned?